# What would the skies look like in a small, positively-curved universe?

Tags: spacetime, universe, curvature

In the positively curved universe going straight would bring you back where you came from. If such a universe were very small, not expanding, and there was only one solar system, we should be able then to see the our solar system in the skies - but how would that look like? How many such mirrored images would we see?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how small the universe is and how old the star is.

A small, positively curved universe has a limited volume. That means that the energy radiated from the star would permeate the whole universe and thus the whole sky. You would not see mirrored images, the entire sky would look all the same.

Let's imagine a starting point: at a certain moment a star lights up. It radiates light in every direction and after some time this light can be found everywhere in the universe. Part of the light emitted will fall back into the star, heating it. This in turn means that the star emits higher frequency light and the process starts over. If I'm not forgetting something fundamental, after enough time the entire universe will be at the same temperature with the center of the star. Or with the temperature the star had when it evaporated.

Comment: It sounds as though you are assuming that this universe is static. If this universe is expanding, than you could expect the universe to gradually cool down with expansion.

Comment: @Bob: Indeed I'm assuming it's static, because the OP wrote: "If such a universe were [...] not expanding". If the universe were expanding, the loss in energy due to redshift would certainly play a role.

Answer (score 0):

If the universe has the topology of a 3-sphere, then rays of light follow great circles. To simplify we can just look at the "equatorial" 2-sphere, which is a normal sphere. Let's put the sun at the north pole of this sphere, and the observer a bit away. They see the sun in the normal way, but also a copy in the opposite direction due to the long way around great circle connecting them. Had the sun been transparent one would have seen the observer behind it (assuming they stayed there long enough - the light takes a finite time to circumnavigate the universe).

If the observer looks in any other direction they will look along a great circle not intersecting the sun, so they only see one extra copy. The same is true for all the other 2-spheres, so the general answer is that the universe looks surprisingly little like a hall of mirrors. However, if the observer moves about they will now see the other image of the sun at their new antisolar point - the image of the sun will shift behind nearby constellations. The same behaviour is true for all other objects in the sky.

Had the universe had the topology of a 3-torus (which is flat rather than positively curved) it would have been a "hall of mirrors"-universe. Generally the positive curvature means that light rays will converge, which means that there will be fewer images of remote things.